# HttpRuntime.Cache deleted after update in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

i'm using `HttpRuntime.Cache` to repeat task. Every cache expire do work and create new cache. Cache start from `application_start`. But i have one problem.

When i update web application `dll`, cache deleted (Not expired) and application_start won't work

How can i solve this problem?

How to create non deletable cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modify the web.config or the contents of the `/bin` directory, this will cause the worker process to reset. So, effectively your application shuts down, and then starts up anew the next request.

The ASP.NET cache is not durable through application restarts. If you need a durable cache, you will need to use an external caching service like memcache, Velocity, NCache, SharedCache, etc.

"application_start won't work" That sounds bewildering. If you provide more detail about that problem, I can try and help with that, too.